# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un array completo como parámetro de una función?

Tags: javascript, loops

Estoy creando en un `for` un `<tr>` y en cada tr tengo un `onclick` el cual le mando a la función `setCity()` con el array `ciudadArr[i]` como parámetro.

Sin embargo, a la hora de hacer click en el resultado la funcion `setCity()` me muestra en la consola solo la letra del ultimo elemento del array. Es decir, si el array tiene `ciudadArr['Uno','Dos','Tres']`, entonces `setCity()` me arrojará la ultima letra del ultimo elemento del array.

Este es mi código:

```
var ciudadArr = new Array();

if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   document.getElementById("resultadosBusqueda1").style.display = 'block';
   console.log(response);
   for (var i = response['length'] - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ciudadArr = response[i]['Ciudad'];
        $("#ciudadTable").append(
            '<tr onclick="setCity(ciudadArr[i])">'+
            '<td width="35%" align="left"><label>'+response[i]['Ciudad']+'</label></td>'+
            '<td width="25%" align="center">'+response[i]['Estado']+'</td>'+
            '<td width="15%" align="center">'+response[i]['Pais']+'</td>'+
            '</tr>');
   }
}

function setCity(Ciudad) {
        console.log(Ciudad); // s
}
```

¿Cómo puedo mandar a la funcion `setCity()` el elemento completo de ese array donde le di click?

Comment: Es un error tipográfico, debería ser `ciudadArr[i] = response[i]['Ciudad'];`, y no `ciudadArr = response[i]['Ciudad'];`

Comment: Dudo que se trate de un error tipográfico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la instrucción 
ciudadArr = response[i]['Ciudad'];

estas igualando el array a solo un elemento, después de recorrer todo el for, será el último.
Deberías hacer un push sobre el array ciudad:
ciudadArr.push(response[i]['Ciudad']);

así el array estará tendrá mas de un elemento.

Comment: Sí! Cometí ese error a la hora de asignarle los valores, también modifiqué la funcion para que quedará así `onclick="setCity(ciudadIdArr['+i+'])"`

Muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Al tener dentro de un for

```
ciudadArr = response[i]['Ciudad'];
```

en cada iteración modifica el valor de ciudadArr

Dado que inicializas la variable con un array vacío, una de las cosas que debes hacer es remplazar la línea en cuestión por

```
ciudadArr.push(response[i]['Ciudad']);
```

Otro punto que podría ser problemático en tu código es

```
'<tr onclick="setCity(ciudadArr[i])">'
```

Pero el código no está completo como para saber si `ciudadArr` e `i` son variables globales.

Comment: Así es el primer problema que cometí fue no guardar en cada iteración el valo y el segundo  problema fue ya con el onclick que lo modifiqué de esta forma `onclick="setCity(ciudadIdArr['+i+'])"`